# How to get only day and month of a date from custom field of wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress, date, custom-post-type

I'm trying to get only day and month of custom field date of wordpress. I've managed to get both but I need to display month and date in different variables.Like: 27JUL.  Here is my code.

```
<?php
   $time = strtotime( get_field( 'date' ) );
   $date = date( 'M d', $time );
   echo "$date";  
 ?>
```

Comment: what is the value from `get_field( 'date' )`?

Comment: just remove the `Y` since it denotes as the year, take it out, just check out the [format](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) that you need

Comment: User can post news or blog date. It's selected from date picker.

Comment: I need to do different css on day and month. So only removing Y won't be enough for me.

Comment: I need to display as: <span class="day">27</span><span class="month">JUL</span>

Comment: What you want exactly only show Month and date in different variable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's your code:

```
<?php
   $time = strtotime( get_field( 'date' ) );
   echo '<span class="day">' . date( 'd', $time ) . '</span><span class="month">' . date( 'M', $time ) . '</span>';
 ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this code:

```
<?php
$date = "2012-01-05";
$time=strtotime($date);
$month=date("F",$time);
$date=date("d",$time);
?>

<span class="day"><?php echo $month; ?></span><span class="month"><?php echo $date; ?></span>
```